# Speeding up a search .net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

Wondering if I can speed up the search.
I need to build a functionality that has to be used by many UI screens
The one I have got works but I need to make sure I am implementing a fast algoritim if you like

It's like an incremental search.

User types a word to search for eg

```
        const string searchFor = "Guinea";
        const char nextLetter = ' '
```

It looks in the list and returns 2 records

```
     "Guinea and Guinea Bissau "
```

User types a word to search for eg

```
        const string searchFor = "Gu";
        const char nextLetter = 'i'

    returns
    3 results.
```

This is the function but I would like to speed it up.
Is there a pattern for this kind of search?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        //Find all countries that begin with string + a possible letter added to it
        //const string searchFor = "Guinea";
        //const char nextLetter = ' ';  //returns 2 results

        const string searchFor = "Gu";
        const char nextLetter = 'i';
        List<string> result = FindPossibleMatches(searchFor, nextLetter);
        result.ForEach(x=>Console.WriteLine(x)); //returns 3 results



        Console.Read();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Find all possible matches 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="searchFor">string to search for</param>
    /// <param name="nextLetter">pretend user as just typed  a letter</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<string> FindPossibleMatches (string searchFor, char nextLetter)
    {
        var hashedCountryList = new HashSet<string>(CountriesList());
        var result=new List<string>();

        IEnumerable<string> tempCountryList = hashedCountryList.Where(x => x.StartsWith(searchFor));

        foreach (string item in tempCountryList)
        {
            string tempSearchItem;
            if (nextLetter == ' ')
            {
                tempSearchItem = searchFor;
            }
            else
            {
                tempSearchItem = searchFor + nextLetter;
            }
            if(item.StartsWith(tempSearchItem))
            {
                result.Add(item);
            }

        }
        return result;
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Returns list of countries.
    /// </summary>
    public static string[] CountriesList()
    {
        return new[]
            {
                "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra",
                "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Antigua And Barbuda", "Argentina",
                "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan",
                "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus",
                "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan",
                "Bolivia", "Bosnia Hercegovina", "Botswana", "Bouvet Island", "Brazil",
                "Brunei Darussalam", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Byelorussian  SSR",
                "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Cayman Islands",
                "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China", "Christmas Island",
                "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo", "Cook Islands",
                "Costa Rica", "Cote D'Ivoire", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus",
                "Czech Republic", "Czechoslovakia", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica",
                "Dominican Republic", "East Timor", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador",
                "England", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia",
                "Falkland Islands", "Faroe Islands", "Fiji", "Finland", "France",
                "Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana",
                "Gibraltar", "Great Britain", "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada",
                "Guadeloupe", "Guam", "Guatemela", "Guernsey", "Guiana",
                "Guinea", "Guinea Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Heard Islands",
                "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India",
                "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Isle Of Man",
                "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jersey",
                "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Korea, South",
                "Korea, North", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Lao People's Dem. Rep.", "Latvia",
                "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein",
                "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macau", "Macedonia", "Madagascar",
                "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta",
                "Mariana Islands", "Marshall Islands", "Martinique", "Mauritania", "Mauritius",
                "Mayotte", "Mexico", "Micronesia", "Moldova", "Monaco",
                "Mongolia", "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar",
                "Namibia", "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles",
                "Neutral Zone", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger",
                "Nigeria", "Niue", "Norfolk Island", "Northern Ireland", "Norway",
                "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea",
                "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Pitcairn", "Poland",
                "Polynesia", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Reunion",
                "Romania", "Russian Federation", "Rwanda", "Saint Helena", "Saint Kitts",
                "Saint Lucia", "Saint Pierre", "Saint Vincent", "Samoa", "San Marino",
                "Sao Tome and Principe", "Saudi Arabia", "Scotland", "Senegal", "Seychelles",
                "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands",
                "Somalia", "South Africa", "South Georgia", "Spain", "Sri Lanka",
                "Sudan", "Suriname", "Svalbard", "Swaziland", "Sweden",
                "Switzerland", "Syrian Arab Republic", "Taiwan", "Tajikista", "Tanzania",
                "Thailand", "Togo", "Tokelau", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago",
                "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Turks and Caicos Islands", "Tuvalu",
                "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States",
                "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Vatican City State", "Venezuela",
                "Vietnam", "Virgin Islands", "Wales", "Western Sahara", "Yemen",
                "Yugoslavia", "Zaire", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"
            };
    }
}
```

}

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Load it in db and do a like query?

Comment: need to do in memory I dont own db

Comment: What is the logical purpose of the nextLetter parameter?

Comment: to find all the countries that have a baseInput EG "Gui" and then type another letter eg "i"

Comment: Not sure how applicable my comment will be but since you mention speed then I'm guessing you're working on a web application. If that's the case and you're looking for speed then this functionality would be an ideal candidate to implement on the client, in javascript, instead of building a server-side component for ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Data structure which is used for prefix searching is TRIE. You can read more about the data structure over here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

You can found couple of c# implementations of trie in following links:
http://www.kerrywong.com/2006/04/01/implementing-a-trie-in-c/

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/is-this-a-reasonable-trie-implementation

Hope this helps in speed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, put all of this in the database and use a SQL query (preferably using the `LIKE` clause) to do the work.  The reason I say this, is that databases are *designed* to do the very thing that you wish to do.  Information storage, and retrieval.

If deploying a full SQL instance is not possible under your requirements, you can always look at [SQLLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki), that has a C# implementation.

Comment: I don't think so.  Working on an in-memory object should be faster than going to an external location such as a database, all else being equal.

Comment: @msigman, as Simon says (ha!), it's all down to the data sets.  My suggestion is based on the fact he wants to search a bunch of things, and perhaps we need to evaluate whether that data needs to be in "code" in the *first* place.

Answer (score 1):

If your data set is static I'd consider using binary search on a sorted array to locate the beginning and the end of the range. Everything in between is your result.